# Vue toggle class based on props

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to toggle a class based on `isNight`'s truth value:

```
<div :class="['app-bg', { nightBg: isNight }]"></div>
```

I have the `isNight` prop set to false as shown:

```
export default {
  name: 'Result',
  data(){
    return {
      error: null,
      weather: null,
      weatherIcon: null,
      isNight: false
    }
  },
  . . .
```

I have a function in computed that returns a true or false based on some data:

```
  computed: {
    nightChecker() {
      return this.weatherIcon.slice(2) == 'n' ? true : false
    }
  },
```

How do I update the `isNight` prop to reflect the return value of `nightChecker()`? I tried `isNight: nightChecker`, but that throws an error.

EDIT: Thank you to everyone who helped me understand this more. As you may can tell, I am new to Vue and am still wrapping my head around it.

Comment: FYI, the `? true : false` is completely redundant

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to change your props from within the component (props are meant to be changed by the parent component). You probably want another computed method that uses the prop and the `nightChecker` method and use it to toggle the class.

Comment: sorry I was confused because the OP said `prop` but it's actually the `data` which is actually internal for the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the error is from `weatherIcon` starting `null`, it's because `null` doesn't have a `slice` method.  You don't need `slice` anyway.

- `slice` returns a range, but since you're only testing against 1 character, it makes more sense to evaluate the index
- By not using `slice`, there is no error even when `weatherIcon` is `null`
- As mentioned in comments, the ternary is unnecessary, you can return the value of the equality check

```js
computed: {
  nightChecker() {
    return !!this.weatherIcon && this.weatherIcon[2] === 'n';
  }
}
```

<sup>The [double not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) is necessary because `null && false` is `null`, not `false`</sup>

Here's a demo if this is still unclear:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      weatherIcon: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    nightChecker() {
      return !!this.weatherIcon && this.weatherIcon[2] === 'n';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.weatherIcon = this.weatherIcon === 'tonight' ? 'today' : 'tonight'
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Is it night? {{ nightChecker }} <br>
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle day/night</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `nightChecker()` method still doesn't do anything to the `isNight` prop that I am trying to change.

Comment: It's not a method, it's a computed.  A computed should never change a data property, it just computes something new.  There is no need for both, you use it instead of `isNight`, which you can eliminate.

Comment: Think of a computed as a data property that changes itself.  It would be pointless to set the value to `isNight`.

Answer (score 0):

idk if i got the question right, but

```
data(){
  return {
    error: null,
    weather: null,
    weatherIcon: null,
    isNight: this.nightChecker()
  }
},
```

```
computed(){
  nightChecker(){
    return this.weatherIcon && this.weatherIcon.slice(2) === 'n';
  }
}
```